# Dependency of Jobs using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dependencies, hierarchy

I have an Oracle table which has 3 columns - schedule name, job name and predecessor. A Job can have multiple entries because it may have multiple satisfying conditions as predecessors. For example,

A may or may not have any predecessor (some schedules might have but not mandatory, considering it as a first job of a schedule)

- A is predecessor to B
- B is predecessor to C
- D may not have any predecessor
- C & D both are predecessors to E

Table data looks like (I just mocked this table - but the real table looks lot messy with thousands of jobs and job names are alphanumeric with a length of 8 chars. Each schedule has few hundreds of jobs).

```
| SCHEDULE | JOB | PREDECESSOR |
|----------|-----|-------------|
| SCHD_A   | A   | XYZ         |
| SCHD_A   | B   | A           |
| SCHD_A   | C   | B           |
| SCHD_A   | D   |     NULL    |
| SCHD_A   | E   | C           |
| SCHD_A   | E   | D           |
```

Could you please help this to achieve in SQL in the same sequence ?
Sort order is the more important for this output. I need to retrieve the list of jobs in the order of its predecessor dependency. Also, I just need to list only the immediate or direct predecessors for any given job like given below:

```
| SCHEDULE | JOB | PREDECESSOR |
|----------|-----|-------------|
| SCHD_A   | A   | XYZ         |
| SCHD_A   | B   | A           |
| SCHD_A   | C   | B           |
| SCHD_A   | D   |     NULL    |
| SCHD_A   | E   | C,D         |
```

I tried using connect clause but my query was incorrect and it did not give expected results.

I tried using LISTAGG but it just lists only the multiple dependencies and it is not taking care of the sort order.

Thanks
CLNS

Comment: `LISTAGG` supports a `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ..)` option.

Comment: But also LISTAGG is limited to the size of the VARCHAR2 on your ORACLE installation (legacy value is 4000), even if latest versions of ORACLE also support overflow handling, this will not give the expected results for thousands of job.
You may have to go to JSON aggregate which supports RETURNING CLOB, unless you have a most recent version with EXTENDED string support activated (then limit will be 32K).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example using LISTAGG() analytic function

```sql
WITH
    a_tbl AS
        (
            Select 'SCHD_A' "SCHEDULE", 'A' "JOB", 'XYZ' "PREDECESSOR" From Dual Union All
            Select 'SCHD_A' "SCHEDULE", 'B' "JOB", 'A'   "PREDECESSOR" From Dual Union All
            Select 'SCHD_A' "SCHEDULE", 'C' "JOB", 'B'   "PREDECESSOR" From Dual Union All
            Select 'SCHD_A' "SCHEDULE", 'D' "JOB", Null  "PREDECESSOR" From Dual Union All
            Select 'SCHD_A' "SCHEDULE", 'E' "JOB", 'C'   "PREDECESSOR" From Dual Union All
            Select 'SCHD_A' "SCHEDULE", 'E' "JOB", 'D'   "PREDECESSOR" From Dual 
        )

Select DISTINCT
    SCHEDULE "SCHEDULE",
    JOB "JOB",
    LISTAGG(PREDECESSOR, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By PREDECESSOR) OVER(PARTITION BY SCHEDULE, JOB) "PREDECESSOR"
From
    a_tbl
Order By
    SCHEDULE,
    JOB
```

The result should be:

| SCHEDULE | JOB | PREDECESSOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SCHD_A | A | XYZ |
| SCHD_A | B | A |
| SCHD_A | C | B |
| SCHD_A | D |  |
| SCHD_A | E | C, D |

LISTAGG() does not order the resulting rows it orders the returning list meaning that if you put it like this:

```sql
LISTAGG(PREDECESSOR, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By PREDECESSOR DESC) OVER(PARTITION BY SCHEDULE, JOB) "PREDECESSOR"
```

... then your aggregated predecessors list would be **'D, C'** instead of 'C, D'.
You order the resulting rows using Order By clause of a Select statement like above - and if you change that Order By clause to

```sql
...
From
    a_tbl
Order By 
    PREDECESSOR,
    SCHEDULE,
    JOB
```

The result should be

| SCHEDULE | JOB | PREDECESSOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SCHD_A | B | A |
| SCHD_A | C | B |
| SCHD_A | E | C, D |
| SCHD_A | A | XYZ |
| SCHD_A | D |  |

Regards...